# groovy regexpression

Tags: regex, groovy

How to get file name from these lines using groovy .

```
File file = new File(SOURCE_FILE_NAME).eachLine{line->
    println line
}
```

getting line like this :

```
/usr/local/
/usr/local/testing.groovy
/usr/local/picture.jpg
```

expecting output:

```
testing.groovy
picture.jpg
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File file = new File(SOURCE_FILE_NAME).eachLine{ path ->
    println org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substringAfterLast(path, "/")
}
```

Comment: Hi, when used ur path , got error java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 16.   
I also had /usr/local/ .may be with this showing error ?. thanks

Comment: thanks don, how to skip for line with out file name extension ?
lines also contains /usr/local, /usr/local/test.org.groovy ....

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about groovy, but the regex you're looking for would be`[^/]+$`

Answer (score 0):

```
println (new File(yourString).name)
```

This should work.

Comment: Hi juriy,

here my  i am doing File file = new File(SOURCE_FILE_NAME).eachLine{line->
println line
}

i was getting /usr/local/testing.groovy. now i need to get only filename excluding the path. thanks

Answer (score 0):

also (no external deps)

```
 ["/usr/local", "/usr/local/testing.groovy", 
  "/usr/local/picture.jpg"].each { item->
    def pat = item =~ /(\w*\/)*(.*)/ 
    if(pat.matches()) {
        println pat.group(2)
    }  
  }
```